# How to insert multi IDs and save in database

Tags: php, database, laravel, multi-select, laravel-7

I'm using Laravel 7 and trying to make a automation system.
For send Letters, I have to be able to choose a few receivers.

Here is Letter table:
[image]

As you can see, I have `recieve_id`.
I can get IDs, but I don't know how to save IDs in my database.

This is my select:

```
<select class="col-12 border mt-2 pt-2" multiple="multiple" name="recieve_id[]">
  @foreach($users as $user)
    <option value="{{ $user->id }}">{{ $user->name }}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

This is my Controller:

```
Letter::create([
  'indicator_id' => $request['indicator_id'],
  'sender_id' => auth()->user()->id,
  'recieve_id' => $request['recieve_id'],
  'title' => $request['title'],
  'image' => 'default.png',
  'description' => $request['description'],
  'date' => $request['date'],
  'text' => $request['text'],
]);
return redirect(route('Letter.index'));
```

Edit:

Here is Table structure:
[image]

Edit 2:

Here is my destory function for letters : 
[Destory Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrJ4p.png)

Comment: are you mean insert multiple rows ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding your question right, the code you have written in the controller is not working well or not creating database entry. Is it right?

If yes, then can you provide me with the table structure you are using for Letter as well as the migration you have written for that particular table?

I am not sure but it seems like you are passing an array `$reciever_id` instead of string and/or JSON string.

Also, if the table in the screenshot you provided, is to be used as the log, then I would suggest to iterate through `$receiver_id` and make a separate entry for each of the receiver if possible. This could be a better approach I think.

EDIT:
After reading your comment, I am modifying my answer as below:
In that case, you should either handle the request with foreach loop as below:

```
$receiver_ids = $request->receive_ids
foreach($receiver_ids as $receiver_id)
{
    Letter::create([
        'indicator_id' => $request['indicator_id'],
        'sender_id' => auth()->user()->id,
        'recieve_id' => $receiver_id,
        'title' => $request['title'],
        'image' => 'default.png',
        'description' => $request['description'],
        'date' => $request['date'],
        'text' => $request['text'],
    ]);
}
```

Put this code in your controller. And let me know.

Comment: Yes, i have an error when click on submit, the error is : Array to string conversion. but type of recieve_id is INT

Comment: Can you share a block of code that you have written?

Comment: see updatet question, i add them to other table before delete

Comment: What is `DeleteLetter`? Is it the different Class? Also what is the significance of `create` method in `destroy` function? I guess whole code is wrong. If you want to delete all records, then `$id` of Letter class won't work for you. I'll update my answer in few hours. Please go through the same

Comment: Before editing my answer, please make me clear what exactly do you expect from `destroy` function. As I can see there are many ways possible for implementation. So, please be specific about what you want to achieve. From your code in the `destroy` function, I am getting a little confused about what you want.

Comment: i have a list of letters, in list, i have a delete button, when i click on delete button, my letter deleted from letter_list, but i dont want to delete complete, so i have a new section, deleted_letter, my code is working, i mean when i click on delete button, letter deleted and insert to new table delete_letter

Comment: Ok... Now I am totally confused what exactly do you want to delete? I mean, on which conditions, the letters are supposed to be deleted? There must be some common attribute you are looking for, apart from `id`.